# SharePoint navigation design issue

Tags: publishing-site, navigation

I am using SharePoint Server 2007 x64 and Windows Server 2008 x64. I have setup a site with template publishing portal. I have grant anonymous access to all the site.

I want to design a two layered navigation solution for the site. And I want to know if there is any advice or document for me to follow-up in order to setup the navigation solution.

In more details, my requirement is:

1. In the top global navigation area, I want to display top categories (car, computer and book)
2. on the left navigation area, I want to display the sub-category for the selected top category from top global navigation area, for example, if computer is selected, I want to display sub-category on left navigation area, like laptop/server/netbook
3. when user clicks a sub-category on the left navigation area, I want to expand sub-category to specific commodity list on the left navigation area (e.g. expand laptop to ThinkPad T60/T61/T400, 3 expanded links on the left navigation area), and when use select a specific commodity, like ThinkPad T60, on the main display area the specific page for the commodity will be displayed -- at the same time, the left side navigation area still remains the same (i.e. display sub-category laptop/server/netbook with expanded ThinkPad T60/T61/T400 for laptop sub-category).

Any documents or advice for such solution? Is it hard or not in SharePoint Server 2007?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple ways you could do this.  One way would be to design a solution through navigation.  Your global navigation uses static links and subcategories display through the OOB menu structure.  There is a walkthrough located at http://erikswenson.blogspot.com/search/label/Global%20Navigation although it uses a secondary top navigation instead of a left nav.  The second option would be to build static links as a top navigation and actually use SharePoint search to display content and drive the secondary left navigation.  The Faceted Search solution from Codeplex can be used to drive the left nav.

Comment: 1. I am confused about "OOB menu structure", OOB means? 2. I looked through the solution, and it looks like an additional control "SPXmlContentMapProvider" is used. I am wondering there is no built-in solution from SharePoint itself?

Comment: @George2: OOB means "out-of-the-box", that is the functionality built-in to the product.